# Getting just certain values of a list in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I get the index of a dataframe when the min of a specific column is located. I do this using the next line of code:

```
mylist = df.Volatilidad_14[df.Volatilidad_14 == df['Volatilidad_14'].min()].index.tolist()
mylist
```

The result is this:

[Timestamp('2010-12-29 00:00:00')]

I just need the date which is after the ' string and before the time 00:00:00. Could someone help me to do that please? The end result should be just: 2010-12-29

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DtatetimeIndex.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
mylist = df.Volatilidad_14[df.Volatilidad_14 == df['Volatilidad_14'].min()].index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but : AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Please check now!:)

Comment: Thanks again ansev, we are getting closer. This is the result:  [datetime.date(2017, 8, 9)] but unfortunately the datetime.date continues there.

Comment: please check second solution!:)

Comment: You are great ansev. It works perfect. The result is this ['2017-08-09']. But I finally can get the final result just with : print(mylist[0]) which is: 2017-08-09. THANKS A LOT.

Answer (score 0):

Does the formatting of this output change at all? If not, it seems like you could simply make a for loop that appends certain indexes to a string. It seems as though you are given back a list with a single item. 
First: set the value of some string, "inString" to equal item 0 of the list.
Second: run a for loop that runs from the range of 11 to 20 (the indexes of your desired section) and have it append the character at each point onto some new empty string, "outString".
This should give you outString being just "2010-12-29".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would always work as I'm quite new myself, but you could index the string by doing

```
mylist = mylist[12:-3]
```

This should output just the numbers you want inside of it!

Comment: Thanks Garden, it makes sense. I tried it but it didn't work either. The result is just: []